# Why word Temp popping up in the beginning of file name

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am saving file to Windows TEMP folder to add it as attachment to my email. For some reason somehow word "Temp" is added all the time to file name. How it comes there and how to prevent it?

NOTE! There is project number in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK2").Value` that does not contain word "Temp"

Here is my code for saving file:

```
    Fname = Environ("temp") & _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK2").Value & ", " & _
    "review" & ".pdf"
```

Here is Outlook code:

```
Sub CreateNewOutlookAppointment()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector

Set olAppt = Nothing
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olAppt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

   Set myInspector = olAppt.GetInspector

   myInspector.Activate

    With olAppt
        .Subject = "review" & ", " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("P23").Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").Range("M202:M223").Copy
        .Display
        .GetInspector.WordEditor.Windows(1).Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPASTERTF

        .Attachments.Add Environ$("Temp") & _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("AK2").Value & ", " & _
        "review" & ".pdf"

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What does `Environ("temp")` return to you?

Comment: Probably you need to add a "\" between the Temp-Folder and the cell content.

Comment: @FunThomas how simple was that! You can add it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Environ$("Temp")` returns the name of your temp-folder, eg `C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp`. Your cell (`AK2`) probably contains a the filename you want to give to the file.

When you concatenate these two parts, you get something like `C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\TempMyFile` - so you create a file with name `TempMyFile` in folder `Local` (or whatever the parent folder of Temp is on your machine).

You simply need to add a `"\"`-character between the (Temp-)path and the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

**Syntax**

```
expression.Add( _Source_ , _Type_ , _Position_ , _DisplayName_ )
```

This parameter applies only if the mail item is in Rich Text format and Type is set to olByValue : the name is displayed in an Inspector object for the attachment or when viewing the properties of the attachment. If the mail item is in Plain Text or HTML format, then the attachment is displayed using the file name in the Source parameter.

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 

 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc", _ 
 olByValue, 1, "Test" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```